# Manage API calls with JavaScript/Python/Bash

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, bash, selenium

I have to choose one of these languages:

- Python (with Selenium or any suggestion)
- Javascript (with `node` with any module)
- Bash (with `curl` for example)

To do the following:

- Make a request to an API (Scrapy cloud) and get some value, in my case I just need the `id` of the response:

> {"count": 1, "id": "195457/7/19", "width": 32, "height": 27, "started_time": "2017-06-22T08:20:26", "total": 1, "status": "ok"}

- And then make another request with the id to download that provides a download to a file with a CSV/JSON format.

What I tried:

**Python:**

With Selenium (Firefox driver) open and get the `id`, it works fine but when I try to download the file with the next API request it asks me for what I want to do with the file (download or open with...). So, as I have to interact with the dialog it is not viable.

**Javascript:**

I found a module to download files but it is just to download files as images from image web URLs and not for download a file (like the Linux `wget` command).

**Bash:**

With `curl` it works but I can just get the whole response and then I cannot get the id value so I cant continue with what I want. Also I tried to download de file of the second step and this works fine with a simple `curl -o myfile.csv URL`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: are you downloading it and saving it on the machine or downloading it though the browser to the user?

Comment: @roughcoder I don't really care how I finally download the file I just want to download it programmatically :)

Comment: Ok, my below answers saves the file to the same folder you run the script from.   If you need something then shout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a node version.  Its quite broad but the 2 main functions are the `callApi` and `downloadFile`.

I dont know the structure of your API url so for me now I have mocked some simple ones - change to what you need.

You will need to `npm install request` and update the variables to match your API.

*index.js*

```
const request = require('request');
const http = require('http');
//const https = require('https'); maybe required
const fs = require('fs');

const apiEndPoint = 'http://scrapycloud?someparam=';
const fileName = 'data.csv';
const assetEndPoint = 'http://assetUrl?id=';

// This will call your api and get the asset id then calls the downloadFile function.
function callApi(assetId, callback) {

    request(apiEndPoint + assetId, function (error, response, body) {

        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }

        const info = JSON.parse(body);
        const assetId = info.id;

        downloadFile(assetId, callback);

    });

}

// This function creates a writeSteam to save a file to your local machine, performs a http request to the assets and pipes it back into the write stream
function downloadFile(assetId, callback) {

    var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
    //use the following line if your requests needs to be https
    //var request = https.get(assetEndPoint + assetId, function (response) {
    var request = http.get(assetEndPoint + assetId, function (response) {
        response.pipe(file);

        file.on('finish', function () {
            file.close(callback);
        });

    }).on('error', function (err) {
        fs.unlink(dest);
        if (callback) callback(err.message);
    });

}

// Called when everything is finished or an error
function complete(err) {

    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('file downloaded');

}

// Starts the process, pass it an id and a callback
callApi('123131', complete);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now I can't test your answer, tomorrow morning I'll say you something. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi! It works the most but when the second request start It gave me an error: https not supported. So I just required it as const and changed the second metod to https.get. Thanks very much!